# How to prevent subclasses from inheriting super class's static method in Swift?

Tags: swift

In the case of the following code, it is possible to call both `Base.f()` and `Sub.f()` because the sub class inherits its parent class's static method.

But I want to use only `Base.f()`, and don't want to use `Sub.f()` in my code.

`Base.f()` and `Sub.f()` do the same thing in the following case.
If both `Base.f()` and `Sub.f()` are used in my code, it just makes my code complex and difficult to find the places where f() are used.

Is it possible to tell swift to generate a compile error if `Sub.f()` is used?

Or, is there an alternative way to do it other than to define f() as a global function?

```
class Base {
    static func f() {
        print("hello world")
    }
}

class Sub: Base {
    
}
```

```
Base.f()
// hello world

Sub.f()
// hello world
```

**EDIT**

More meaningful example than printing "hello world".

In the following case, I don't want to call it with `Sub1.findSubclassByType("sub2")` because `Sub1` finding a subclass sounds funny.
So, I want to always call it with `Base.findSubclassByType("sub2")`.

Maybe, defining `findSubclassByType(type)` in `Base` is a wrong design of a class? (Although, it is convenient that Xcode suggests `findSubclassByType(type)` when I type `Base.`.)

What should I do?

```
class Base {

    static func findSubclassByType(_ type: String) -> Base {
        
        // find and return a subclass
         
        if type == "sub1" {
            return Sub1()

        } else if type == "sub2" {
            return Sub2()

        } else {
            fatalError("no sub class")
        }

    }
    
}

class Sub1: Base {
}

class Sub2: Base {
}
```

Comment: A really _bad_ solution IMO would be to use a `class func` instead, so that you can override it in the subclass and use `@available(*, unavailable)`. But I think that's abusing language features.

Comment: you can use `final` to prevent overriding

Comment: Why don't you make `f` only be a static method on a specific subclass of `Base`? E.g. a class called `WelcomingBase` that implements that method and can be used like any other `Base`.

Comment: If you can use `final func f()` instead that can generate compiler error

Comment: If the function is static then you can move it out of that class and into a new (final) class or a struct and there will be only one way to access it.

Comment: @ChanOnly123 - `static` functions are already `final`, so adding `final` is redundant and is not permitted.

Comment: I’d suggest that the cure (preventing `Sub.f()` references) is worse than the disease (your challenge in finding `f()` references in your code). Sure, as Joakim said, you could just move it into some other final class (or a struct) so it’s not inherited. Or you could leave it as is and write some script to check for this undesirable usage and add it to your build phases. But subclasses inherit their parent functions, and I’m not sure it’s worth all that effort to achieve non-standard behavior. It strikes me as the sort of thing that feels useful right now, but that you may eventually regret.

Comment: FWIW, another option to consider is tools like [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint). It offers all sorts of stylistic rules and you can add your own, too, e.g, for this particular misuse of your function. It integrates nicely into Xcode, too, so you can get warnings or errors about code style when you compile.

Comment: @Joakim thank you. creating a new (final) class or a struct seems to be a better solution than defining it as global function in this case.

Comment: @Sweeper adding @available(*, unavailable) to all subclasses' static methods is a little complex because it won't work if i forget to make subclass's static function unavailable, but your solution is nice if i absolutely want to use f() only with `Base.f()`.

Comment: @Rob the benefit of using `Base.f()` is that i can get code completion suggestions when typing `Base.`. so, sometimes it is more useful than defining it on other (final) class or struct or defining it as global function.

Comment: i need or swift needs an attribute or keyword like `@noInherit static func f()`. i think if `final` keyword is not a bad language feature, `@noInherit` attribute or keyword also should not be a bad idea.

Comment: I seriously doubt that a “no inherit” would ever be integrated into the language. It is antithetical to OO inheritance and violates beloved OO design principles (e.g. SOLID’s LSP, OCP, etc.).

Comment: @Rob thank you. could you post an answer and show me how "no inherit" violates LSP and OCP? i understand, in general, "no inherit" might violates something but i think methods like printing "hello world" which doesn't depend on the subclasses' implementation can't violate any principles because it is equivalent to a global function. printing "hello world" is useless but how about `Base.findSubclassByType(_ type: String) { /*find and return a subclass*/ }`? in this case, i don't want to call it with `Sub1.findSubclassByType("sub2")`. i want to always use `Base.findSubclassByType("sub2")`.

Comment: @Rob i added another code example in my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239641/discussion-between-rob-and-user).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments of my question contains many good answers:

- there is no dedicated swift feature to prevent subclasses from inheriting super class static methods.
- move static functions to a new (final) class or struct
- use `class` instead of `static (=final class)` and override the class method and add `@available(*, unavailable)` to it.
- use Lint tools

I think the easiest way is to create a new (final) class for static methods which do not depend on subclasses, though, that sacrifices code completion feature a little.

I hope someday Swift will introduce `@noInherit static func` attribute.

**EDIT**

I found another way to restrict the way to call a static method in runtime:

```
class Base {
    static func f() {
        if Self.self != Base.self {
            fatalError("don't call from subclass: " + String(describing: Self.self))
        }

        print("hello world")
    }
}
```

**note**: The disadvantage of the EDIT is that it is checked only in runtime. The benefit of it is that you need only 3 lines and you don't need to override the static method in all subclasses. But this way should be used only when you have confident that checking in runtime is enough and safe for your app.

Comment: This edit is bad. Your first comment from Sweeper is how to handle that.

Comment: @Jessy yes, it is not very good because it is checked in runtime. but the benefit of the way of the edit is that you don't need to override f() in all subclasses but you just need to write that `if statement` in the base static method. you might forget override and add `unavailable` especially when you have some static functions and subclasses. every way including yours have own good points and bad points. and in Swift you have to use fatalError() to prevent parent's abstract methods from calling in runtime if using a protocol is not suitable.

Comment: @Jessy thank you for the comment. i added a `note` to the edit.

Answer (score 0):

What you're precisely asking is impossible, because the only public/internal members that are not inherited by subclasses are initializers—and only when a subclass defines its own designated initializer, without implementations of all of its superclass's initializers.

So, to abuse that capability, you can use failable initializers when you don't need a return value…

```swift
class Base {
  init() { }
  
  @discardableResult init?(printingHelloWorld: Void) {
    print("hello world")
    return nil
  }
}

class Sub: Base {
  init(_: Any) {
    super.init()
  }
}
```

```swift
Base(printingHelloWorld: ())
```

…or throwing initializers, when you do.

```swift
class Base {
  init() { }
  
  struct Error: Swift.Error {
    let payload: String
  }
  
  init(returningAPayload: @autoclosure () -> Never) throws {
    throw Error(payload: "")
  }
}

class Sub: Base {
  init(_: Any) {
    super.init()
  }
}

extension Never {
  init() { fatalError() }
}
```

```swift
do {
 try Base(returningAPayload: .init())
} catch {
  (error as! Base.Error).payload
}
```

I advise against any of this, and subclassing in general.

Comment: thank you! i've tried your code and it worked. i found that the subclass has to have its own init() NOT to inherit its parent's inits. but in most cases, every sub class has its own init. i learned a lot from your example code. i didn't know `Void` argument type, `@autoclosure`, and `Never` enum.